# ThirdPersonMovement script Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following this video: https://youtu.be/4HpC--2iowE?t=686

And after making the thirdpersonmovement script, I get an error that he did not get. Can anyone help me? There's probably a very small error that I cannot see, I must be blind. I followed the exact steps.

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 6f;

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
       float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       float vetrical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
       Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

       if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
       {
           controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
       }
   }
```

}

---

Error:

Assets\Scripts\ThirdPersonMovement.cs(16,57): error CS0103: The name 'Vertical' does not exist in the current context

Says error is on line 16. where "vector3 direction" is located

If the code is kinda wonky sorry, first time using this, was a weird set up for me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Says error is on line 16. where "vector3 direction" is located

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`  .. also just because you use a certain IDE (`visual-studio`) doesn't mean your question is about that IDE in specific .. what you want is the tag `unity3d` since that is the main framework/API you are using here

Comment: Alright so don't tag any of the programs I am working with or using, just C# and Unity3D because I am working on unity on 3D projects? But then that also sounds weird.

Comment: you tag `c#` and `unity3d` as this are the language and API you are asking a question about. You are not asking about a `unityscript` code nor about something that is specific to `visual-studio` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
vetrical
vertical
```

t and r are swapped

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)